# gfortran open error messages

Tags: fortran, iostat

I seem to remember the open in gfortran has the possibility to return the result of iostat as a string, but I have forgotten the option name to return the string.

Does anybody remember the parameter to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/n1551-n1600/n1579.pdf:

> IOMSG= specifier: Any input/output statement is permitted to have an
>   IOMSG= specifier. This identifies a scalar variable of type default
>   character into which the processor places a message if an error,
>   end-of-file, or end-of-record condition occurs during execution of the
>   statement. If no such condition occurs, the value of the variable is
>   not changed.